# OSX - Qt Modeless child dialog without auto positioning

Tags: c++, macos, qt, dialog

Is it possible to create child modeless dialog on OSX whose position will not be changed on any parent window position change?

I'm creating child window in common way:

```
g_pWndNormal = new CToolWindow(this);
g_pWndNormal->show();
```

On Windows/Linux this works normally. Child window has it's own position and user can set child window position independently on the main window. Unfortunately on OSX when main (parent) window position is changed, all child windows are repositioned.

[Here is a short video how child window behaves on OSX.](http://screencast.com/t/ITEJ8fuPRW)

Is there any way how to turn this behavior off?

Comment: Do you need to parent this window? If not, pass NULL to the CToolWindow constructor.